# Untangle re.findall capturing groups: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Tags: python, regex

This function highlights certain keywords in a string with color. `Fore.CYAN` and `Fore.RESET` are from the [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) module.

Is there a way to insert `regex` instead of the list `["This", "words", "annotate"]`?

```
from colorama import Fore

def highlight(var, keywords):
    replacement = Fore.CYAN + "\\1" + reset()
    var = re.sub("(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)) + ")", replacement, var, re.I)
        print var + Fore.RESET

string = "This string contains words to annotate"

highlight(string, ["This", "words", "annotate"])
```

I have tried this:

```
regex_keywords = re.findall(r"(This)|(Words)|(Annotate)", string, re.I)

highlight(string, regex_keywords)
```

Does not work as it complains about `'list' object has no attribute 'join'"`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: @Cyphase Thanks for asking. I'm trying to use a regex rule instead of `["This", "words", "annotate"]`. This would allow for more flexibility for which keywords to highlight.

Comment: That's a detail; what are you trying to _do_? :) What are you trying to accomplish with this code? It'll be really useful if you can show some sample input and output.

Comment: @Cyphase: The problem is solved thanks to the answer below. The problem was simply that the list was placed inside another list. If you still would like me to answer your question, I will try to exemplify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`higlight` needs any iterable over strings. You have a list of list of tuple of strings. Remove the parentheses and forget about the tuple:

```
regex_keywords = re.findall(r"This|Words|Annotate", string, re.I)
highlight(string, regex_keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks, however that gives `AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'join'"`. I will edit out the tuple conversion from the question.

Comment: @Winterflags: didn't see the parentheses in the regexp. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I didn't realize I should do this without capturing groups. Should have tried that sooner :)